# Install ffmpeg on Netgear NAS running custom Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, apt, ffmpeg, aptitude

I have a Netgear NAS ("ReadyNAS Duo v2") running a custom variant of  Debian 6.0.3 "squeeze", named "RAIDiator-arm 5.3.12" and there are no further upgrades as the device is [no longer supported](http://www.netgear.com/support/product/rnd2000v2_(readynas_duo_v2).aspx?cid=wmt_netgear_organic).

I would like to install ffmpeg on this system but there are some conflicting packages. Here is the output of `aptitude install ffmpeg`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libavfilter0: Depends: libavcodec52 (< 4:0.5.10-99) 
                         but 4:0.6.6-.netgear2 is installed. or 
                         libavcodec-extra-52 (< 4:0.5.10-99) which is a virtual package.
  libavdevice52: Depends: libavcodec52 (< 4:0.5.10-99) 
                          but 4:0.6.6-1.netgear2 is installed. or
                          libavcodec-extra-52 (< 4:0.5.10-99) which is a virtual package.
                 Depends: libavformat52 (< 4:0.5.10-99) 
                          but 4:0.6.6-1.netgear2 is installed. or
                          libavformat-extra-52 (< 4:0.5.10-99) which is a virtual package.
```

It appears some netgear-specific version of the libavcodec52 package is hindering the installation. What can I do?

I had the idea of cross-compiling a static build of ffmpeg on my computer but [run into other problems](https://superuser.com/q/1166220/196542).

Comment: try installing newer ffmpeg. newer than 4:0.6.6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But how can I do that? apt wants to install version 4:0.5.10-1 (armel), so I assume I would have to use some kind of manual method that does not involve a package manager?

Comment: there is [squeeze-backports](http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports/dists/squeeze-backports/) repo with ffmpeg=6:0.8.6-1~bpo60+1

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your apt sources.list file.  Debian moved squeeze to the archive.

I would post my sources.list file, but stackexchange won't let me post more than 2 urls.  Essentially you need to update all the ftp.us.debian.org to archive.debian.org.